# Missing tittle and author

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I have a Rmd (see bellow) file and when I execute the file without toc and pandoc I am able to get the title and author, but with them I am not able to see them. How can I get my title and author name to appear with numbered sections and toc?

```
---
title: "Design"
author: "Jen"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    pandoc_args: [
      "--number-sections"
    ]
  
---

# plots
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should give `rmarkdown` full control over the pandoc arguments:

```
---
title: "Design"
author: "Jen"
output:
  html_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
---

# plots
```

Source: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/html-document.html#section-numbering